# How to iterate python windowed() to last element?

Tags: python-3.x

According to the [more_itertools.windowed](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.windowed) specification, you can do:

```
list(windowed(seq=[1, 2, 3, 4], n=2, step=1))

>>> [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]
```

But what if I want to run it all to the end? Is it possible to get:

```
>>> [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, None)]
```

Comment: If you are sliding to the right by 2 with `step=2` then wouldn't the next windowed tuple output be `(None, None, None)` instead of `(6, None, None)` ?

Comment: you are correct, i have rephrased the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround but not the best solution is to append None with the sequence.

```
list(windowed(seq=[1, 2, 3, 4,None], n=2, step=1))
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do this programmatically based on the `step=` value which I refer to as `win_step` in the following code.  I also removed hardcoding where possible to make it easier to test various `sequence_list`, `win_width`, and `win_step` data sets:

```
sequence_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
win_width = 2
win_step = 1
none_list = []
for i in range(win_step):
    none_list.append(None)
sequence_list.extend(none_list)
tuple_list = list(windowed(seq=sequence_list, n=win_width, step=win_step))
print('tuple_list:', tuple_list)
```

Here are my results based on your original question's data set, and on the current data set:

For original, where:

```
sequence_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
win_width = 3
win_step = 2
```

The result is:

```
tuple_list: [(1, 2, 3), (3, 4, 5), (5, 6, None), (None, None, None)]
```

And for the present data set, where:

```
sequence_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
win_width = 2
win_step = 1
```

The result is:

```
tuple_list: [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, None)]
```